# After Deleting some Python Files, I can't install pytorch any more via pip

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, pytorch, macos-catalina

Unfortunately I deleted some files of Python. I got macOS Catalina and I want to install pytorch with the command:

```
pip3 install torch
```

If I enter this in my terminal I'll get

> Building wheel for torch (setup.py) ... error
>     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>      command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-qh35w11o --python-tag cp38
>          cwd: /private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/
>     Complete output (30 lines):
>     running bdist_wheel
>     running build
>     running build_deps
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       File "/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py", line 225, in 
>         setup(name="torch", version="0.1.2.post2",
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 145, in setup
>         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
>         dist.run_commands()
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
>         self.run_command(cmd)
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>         cmd_obj.run()
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
>         self.run_command('build')
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>         self.distribution.run_command(command)
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>         cmd_obj.run()
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
>         self.run_command(cmd_name)
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>         self.distribution.run_command(command)
>       File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>         cmd_obj.run()
>       File "/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py", line 51, in run
>         from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
>     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
>
> ---
>
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
>     Running setup.py clean for torch
>     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>      command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
>          cwd: /private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch
>     Complete output (2 lines):
>     running clean
>     error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'
>
> ---
>
> ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
>   Failed to build torch
>   Installing collected packages: torch
>       Running setup.py install for torch ... error
>       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-record-cerpeh7h/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
>            cwd: /private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/
>       Complete output (23 lines):
>       running install
>       running build_deps
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py", line 225, in 
>           setup(name="torch", version="0.1.2.post2",
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 145, in setup
>           return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
>           dist.run_commands()
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
>           self.run_command(cmd)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py", line 99, in run
>           self.run_command('build_deps')
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>           self.distribution.run_command(command)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py", line 51, in run
>           from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
>       ----------------------------------------
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-kb_zrdjk/torch/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-record-cerpeh7h/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Do you need further Information?

**UPDATE**

I changed the way of the enviroment (without anaconda) and so I get this error message:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-zelcwulm/torch/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-install-zelcwulm/torch/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/sb/4h99w30940zcbdvy_csrksxc0000gn/T/pip-record-i1_7akf_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

If that doesn't work you can always try reinstalling python from https://www.python.org/downloads

Comment: it doesn't work, so i changed the enviroment. But there is a new error message. I updated the main post here. Is there a other way to solve it?

Comment: @Seems I am afraid I am not too sure what this new error is, could you post the whole thing, or is that is?

Comment: @Seems could you please post the error for pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip

Comment: There is no error if I execute this command. But this command changed nothing.

Comment: @Seems, try uninstalling python and reinstalling it